# Authentication for each Request in each Controller in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

**Base Controller**

```
class MyBaseController extends Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
       if (Auth::check()) {
            // The user is logged in...
       }
       else {
            //Redirect to login page
       }
    }   

}
```

**Controller that will have database calling functions and will be available for logged in users only**

```
class ChildController extends MyBaseController {

    public function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }   
}
```

**What do I need ?**

I want to check each request if that is made by an authenticated user ?

**Question:**

Is my approach correct or is this best practice to check if the call to this controller is made by authenticated user ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best would be to use [Middlewares](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/middleware).

You can simply define a route group like this and add a middleware.

```
Route::group([
    'middleware' => 'auth',
], function() {

    // Your routes here...

});
```

Comment: is there any tool to go to definition of the function in Laravel ? +1

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there, you need to use this concept of middleware. There is a built in middleware for Session based authentification simply called "auth".

```
//in your controller :
public function __construct() {
   $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

You can learn more about [middlewares and controllers](http://laravel.com/docs/master/controllers#controller-middleware) in the docs